# Value extraction from a variable unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I have a variable named as output which holds value as below -

Code:

```
output=[record
  bdfo_len      73
  bdfo_key      "     200000016"
  bdfo_param_no "000"
  parm01        NULL
  parm02        NULL
  parm03        NULL
  parm04        NULL
  parm05        NULL
  parm06        NULL
  parm07        NULL
  parm08        NULL
  parm09        NULL
  parm13        NULL
  parm16        NULL
  parm017       NULL
  parm18        NULL
  parm93        NULL
  parm94        NULL
  parm96        NULL
  parm97        NULL
  parm83        NULL
  header        [record
                  bdfo_run_date     41991
                  bdfo_file_id      "GYFL3027"
                  bdfo_centre_id    "G"
                  bdfo_sbi_file_ind "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"]
  trailer       NULL
  data          NULL]
```

I need to extract bdfo_run_date value which is '41991' out of this, any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, If any of the following answer helped you then please acknowledge by accepting the answer by ticking the right sign beside the answer.  You can also upvote others who are providing multiple approaches to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "$output"|grep -oP 'bdfo_run_date\s+\K[^ ]+'
41991
```

`-o` : To print only the matching string not the whole line.
`-p` : To enable perl regex.

`regex:` bdfo_run_date followed by one or more space characters. `\K` will remove everything left to it.